# Laravel FileManager on 000Webhost - i can't upload files/images

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, upload

This is my first time when i post ask here, but it's not the first time when i see any solutions.

I have a real problem with my laravel project and my website where host on 000Webhost.

I explain the problem :

I have create laravel project like another developper can create it, i created controllers/migrations/models/views/routes, also i uses Framework CSS and Templates...

I would like to create some News like lot of website, with title, description, and article and some images. To do this, i have search any solution laravel can have. At the begining i choose elFinder WebManager, it's a good webmanager but i've meet lot problem with it, so i change to Laravel FileManager last week, and i prefer it for interface and configuration.

Alright my project works locally with wamp server 64, no problem with Laravel or Laravel File Manager, i can upload, create folder etc... So i put my project on my 000webhost site, i change configuration for it, and i see what's works and what's doesn't works.
All project works good, the routes are the same, views are goods and authentication too. But not the upload of Laravel FileManager. I can create folder, i can choose images from my project uploaded initilialy but i can't upload images from my pc to my website. When i try to upload, error message spawn and said "File failed to upload. Error code: 6".

I'm very frustred, because it's the only problem do i have on this project with at this moment, no good solutions.

I search what is problem on forums or on the net, i see guys who are problem with permissions on 000Webhost, so i try to change my permissions of my folders where laravel filemanager are installed. All my folders in my website are on 777 permissions and nothing works. I need to find a solution it's important for me but i see nobody's search an solution for this problem or i have skip it by inadvertence (so i'm sorry for this subject).

I search any others solutions or others anwsers to enable achievement my project.

If you want any informations, i can send it here.

I'm present for any questions if you needed..

Thank's you for reading and if you have answered it in advance.

Cordially,

Answer (score 0):

Error code 6 indicates that a [tmp directory has not been specified](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). You'll need to provide a tmp directory in your php.ini using the [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) directive.